# Parsing Outlook Emails for text that is one line below the identifying label

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to transfer data from email forms to Excel.

Emails are formatted like..

> Form Submission:
>
> **Select place:**
> STACK
>   **First name:**
> John
>   **Last name:**
> Doe
>   **Phone number:**
> 07555555555
>   **Email:**
> john.doe@example.com
>   **Query String:**

I want to use a delimiter to separate the variable strings.

I tried adjusting a similar code but this doesn't separate the information properly.

```
Sub Extract1()

Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim topOlFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myOlFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myOlMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set myOlFolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder




Set xlObj = CreateObject("excel.application")
xlObj.Visible = True
xlObj.Workbooks.Add

Set anchor = xlObj.Range("a1")

anchor.offset(0, 0).Value = "Place"
anchor.offset(0, 1).Value = "First"
anchor.offset(0, 2).Value = "Last"
anchor.offset(0, 3).Value = "Phone"
anchor.offset(0, 4).Value = "Email"


Dim msgText As String
Dim msgLine() As String
Dim messageArray() As String

i = 0
      For Each myOlMailItem In myOlFolder.Items

    i = i + 1


    msgText = myOlMailItem.Body

    messageArray = Split(msgText, vbCrLf)

    For j = 0 To UBound(messageArray)

        msgLine = Split(messageArray(j) & ":", ":")

        Select Case Left(msgLine(0), 5)

            Case "Select"
                anchor.offset(i, 0).Value = messageArray(j + 1)

            Case "First"
                anchor.offset(i, 1).Value = messageArray(j + 1)

            Case "Last "
                anchor.offset(i, 2).Value = messageArray(j + 1)

            Case "Phone"
                anchor.offset(i, 3).Value = messageArray(j + 1)

            Case "Email"
                anchor.offset(i, 4).Value = messageArray(j + 1)

        End Select


    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Result should be formatted like this.

```
Place     First     Last     Phone         Email
STACK     John      Doe      07555555555   john.doe@example.com
```

So at the moment it just isn't copying over the select...I feel like I'm being realllly stupid.

Comment: I should point out this does split up the headers fine, but the whole email body is then pasted into the first column of the next row

Comment: First and foremost, banish `On Error Resume Next` from your repertoire until you're no longer a noob. That tells your code to completely ignore and and all errors that may crop up. There are legitimate uses for it, but they're few and far between. Second, what _is_ the code giving you? Edit your actual results into your OP.

Comment: In the VB editor click on the Tools menu then Options then Editor tab then the Checkbox "Require Variable Declaration". This will generate Option Explicit at the top of new modules. Go ahead and type this in manually at the top of your existing module now. This as well helps fix spelling errors in the variables. `delimtedMessage`  vs `delimitedMessage`

Comment: Fixed the spelling errors, also now code above doesn't seem to work at all :/

Comment: `Option Explict` would help immensely but it appears you still do not see the benefit of declaring the variables. Make these changes to bring your question into a possibly answerable state. `delimitedMessage = myItem.body`, "Select Place:" not "Select place:", "First Name:", "Last Name:" and "Phone Number:".

Comment: I tried doing the above. It did fix the issue of not opening excel. However now I get 'Runtime error '9': Subscript out of range.' Also there is a lot of unneeded text after the email.

Comment: Take a look at how `Replace` is used in sequence and `Split` is used once only. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639005/1571407. Edit the question with changed code where the original text is processed only once. Subsequently `Replace` acts on the changed text in delimitedMessage. Remember to use the exact text of the mail with appropriate capital letter on the second word.

Comment: ok so I've changed the code quite a bit with another example I've seen that I seem to understand a bit more. Can someone help with why I can't get it to use each email in the current folder to input a new set of data in to the next row?

Answer (score 0):

The vbCrLf is the/an answer with either your current or previous code. The rest is just debugging.

With your current code and using test emails with text copy/pasted from the sample.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Extract2()

    'Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application     ' Not necessary if code in Outlook
    'Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.namespace   ' Not used
    'Dim topOlFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder  ' Necessary for 2003

    Dim topOlFolder As folder               ' 2007 and subsequent
    Dim myOlFolder As folder

    'Dim myOlMailItem As mailItem
    ' The type of item in a folder is not necessarily a mailitem
    Dim myOlMailItem As Object

    Dim xlObj As Object
    Dim Anchor As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    'Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
    'Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Set myOlFolder = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set myOlFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    Set xlObj = CreateObject("excel.application")
    xlObj.Visible = True
    xlObj.Workbooks.Add

    Set Anchor = xlObj.Range("a1")

    Anchor.Offset(0, 0).Value = "Place"
    Anchor.Offset(0, 1).Value = "First"
    Anchor.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Last"
    Anchor.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Phone"
    Anchor.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Email"

    Dim msgText As String
    'Dim msgLine() As String
    Dim messageArray() As String

    i = 1

    'Perhaps instead
    'i = 0

    ' You should have indicated there was an error in this line
    'For Each myOlMailItem In myOlFolder
    For Each myOlMailItem In myOlFolder.Items

        If myOlMailItem.Class = olMail Then

            Debug.Print myOlMailItem.subject

            i = i + 1

            msgText = myOlMailItem.body

            messageArray = Split(msgText, vbCrLf)

            For j = 0 To UBound(messageArray)

                ' this seems unnecessary
                'msgLine = Split(messageArray(j) & ":", ":")
                'Select Case Left(msgLine(0), 5)

                Debug.Print "Left(messageArray(j), 5): " & Left(messageArray(j), 5)
                Select Case Left(messageArray(j), 5)

                'Case "Select"
                ' Typo
                Case Left("Select", 5)

                    Debug.Print "messageArray(j): " & messageArray(j)
                    Debug.Print "messageArray(j + 1): " & messageArray(j + 1)
                    Debug.Print "messageArray(j + 2): " & messageArray(j + 2)
                    'Anchor.Offset(i, 0).Value = messageArray(j + 1)
                    Anchor.Offset(i, 0).Value = messageArray(j + 2)

                Case "First"
                    'Anchor.Offset(i, 1).Value = messageArray(j + 1)
                    Anchor.Offset(i, 1).Value = messageArray(j + 2)

                Case "Last "
                    'Anchor.Offset(i, 2).Value = messageArray(j + 1)
                    Anchor.Offset(i, 2).Value = messageArray(j + 2)

                Case "Phone"
                    'Anchor.Offset(i, 3).Value = messageArray(j + 1)
                    Anchor.Offset(i, 3).Value = messageArray(j + 2)

                Case "Email"
                    'Anchor.Offset(i, 4).Value = messageArray(j + 1)
                    Anchor.Offset(i, 4).Value = messageArray(j + 2)

                End Select

                ' You should have indicated there was an error in this line
                ' Appears to be unnecessary anyway
                'Anchor.Offset(i, -1).Value = i

            Next

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I understand the code a lot more now. For some reason this doesn't paste the selected data in to the sheet. It just creates the headers and then loops without selecting or having anything pasted in to the second row.

Comment: It appears blanks are found. See edited code. If still finding blanks, follow the same process to find the non-blanks.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3GkdUk7s here is a link to a pastebin with how the email comes. When I adjust the J element it may recognise the right line for the first item but then doesn't when it loops to another. It also is still not printing in excel. I appreciate your help niton

Comment: Just trying to bump this question as I still haven't got a full solution :P